# How could the no named clan win the trial of annihilation?

Tags: battletech

As it is stated in this question and its answer: [Can a member of the not named clan ask for a trial of refusal to save his clan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148797/can-a-member-of-the-not-named-clan-ask-for-a-trial-of-refusal-to-save-his-clan/148811#148811) the original trial of annihilation is still going on (as some of the original clan warriors managed to flee and were the so called minnesota (spelling?) tribe mentioned within the inner sphere.

As the original trial is still going on and they usually win it by eliminating the other side that was part of the bid (or later upgrades) the question is...is it possible somehow by the no named clan to win the trial of annihilation (during the 3050s as example) and if so what would they have to do to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Trial is not still going on because even though some Wolverines survived and fled and may have descendants out there somewhere, the official Clan position is that nobody survived and any discrepancies in body counts and whatnot are down to "bad bookkeeping" (*The Clans: Warriors of Kerensky*, p13). So even though not all warriors were killed nor were all civilians accounted for, Clan Wolverine officially ceased to exist in 2823.

So, no, it is not possible for the Wolverines to win the Trial of Annihilation because they have already lost it.

One of the examples given in *Warriors of Kerensky* is a Clan Star that was annihilated and the result of that Annihilation cascaded down to anyone sharing their genes so that several hundred individuals ended up paying the price even though only 5 persons were subject to the Trial. This would be similar; the actual target of the Annihilation (i.e., Clan Wolverine) has been taken care of and the results of that successful Trial automatically apply to anyone sharing their genes. That doesn't mean, however, that the original Trial hasn't been settled and closed out.

Comment: Interesting although "bloodname" (sourcebook) states that the remaining members are hunted down and everyone killing them automatically earns the right to create a new bloodname. so that is not the original tiral then?

Comment: It's more like cleaning up loose ends, I suppose. The Trial of Annihilation proper is over but there are still some potential outliers to take care of.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example from a sourcebook that is similar to the Wolverine situation.

Answer (score 1):

## No, because Nicholas Kerensky Lied

As far as the Clans are concerned, the Not-Named Clan was destroyed utterly and completely, after they used a nuclear bomb to destroy another Clan's genetic heritage, amongst other crimes.

All of these claims, as revealed in the canon book *Betrayal of Ideals*, are in actuality *lies*.

The nuclear detonations, plural, were neither done by Clan Wolverine. The first was a frame-up job, the second was an accident.

Clan Wolverine was just challenging the new order of the Clans, specifically the caste system. Their power and influence was growing rampantly and their rival Clans conspired behind their backs to turn Nicholas Kerensky against them to destroy them, completely and utterly.

Nicholas Kerensky outright ordered the Clans to lie so thoroughly and utterly that the Clans firmly and inescapably believe the lies as the truth, to the point where if you told them the REAL truth, they'll probably kill you on the spot for lying- just saying the name of Clan Wolverine is viewed as a crime. He knew the truth, but ordered the falsities to be recorded so that all Clans would believe in his goals. Once those few who died, there would be no proof.

And even if they did, by Clan mindset they'd probably consider those who ran traitorous cowards who conceded the Trial the moment they went running away.